# How is Tags post % calculated in Stack Overflow?

Tags: support

I am interested to know on what basis tags post percentage is calculated. For example as you can see below, in `awk` tag, score is `150` and posts are `109` and posts % is `46`.

Can someone tell me know it is calculated?

[image][image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The percentages are relative to the number of posts you created. You created 236 posts (visible in your screenshot), and 46% of those were tagged `awk`.

This is easily verified:

```
>>> (109 / 236) * 100
46.186440677966104
```

The same goes for the other tags:

```
>>> (99 / 236) * 100  # php, 42%
41.94915254237288
>>> (42 / 236) * 100  # bash, 18%
17.796610169491526
>>> (45 / 236) * 100  # arrays, 19%
19.06779661016949
```

etc.

Comment: How to you calculate 236 posts.Total posts are more than 300 here @MartijnPieters

Comment: @AkashBisariya the screenshot tells you (*Top Posts (236)*). A post can have more than one tag, so don't just sum up the tag counts. Besides, the percentages add up to more than 100%, so there can't be more than 300 posts.